# controlling multiple entry buttons with the same 2 control buttons

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I believe this code is close - I have three buttons defined with a callback to store a IntVar() variable associated with the button selected.  I have created a temp variable (cntr) that stores the appropriate Intvar.  that seems to be working based on the print statements I have in the callbacks.  but when I select one of those buttons then hit the inc or dec button configured at the end of the code, the only "entry" button that changes is the one that setup in the main section of the code.  Can anyone show me what I am missing

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import PhotoImage

def increment (cntr):
    print('in inc', cntr)
    cntr.set("{0:0>4}".format(cntr.get() + 1))

def decrement (cntr):
    print('in dec', cntr)
    cntr.set("{0:0>4}".format(cntr.get() - 1))

def EntryCB(arg):
    global cntr
    cntr = arg
    print('in EntryCB', cntr, arg)

root = Tk()
root.configure(bg='white')
frame1 = LabelFrame(root, text="Component 1",) 
frame1.grid()

#UpArrow = PhotoImage(file="images//UpArrow.png")
#DownArrow = PhotoImage(file="images/DownArrow.png")

counter1 = IntVar()
counter1.set("{0:0>4}".format(0))
counter2 = IntVar()
counter2.set("{0:0>4}".format(0))
counter3 = IntVar()
counter3.set("{0:0>4}".format(0))
cntr=counter1

print('in main', cntr)

#setup entry buttons tied to IntVar variables
Entry1 = Button(frame1, textvariable=counter1)
Entry1.grid(row=0, column=0)
Entry1.config(command= lambda arg=counter1:EntryCB(arg))
Entry1.configure(borderwidth=3, relief='sunken', bg='green')
Entry2 = Button(frame1, textvariable=counter2)
Entry2.grid(row=0, column=1)
Entry2.config(command= lambda arg=counter2:EntryCB(arg))
Entry2.configure(borderwidth=3, relief='sunken', bg='pink')
Entry3 = Button(frame1, textvariable=counter3)
Entry3.grid(row=0, column=2)
Entry3.config(command= lambda arg=counter3:EntryCB(arg))
Entry3.configure(borderwidth=3, relief='sunken', bg='orange')

#setup callback and display control buttons to increment or decrement the IntVar
Inc = Button(frame1,text='Inc')
Inc.grid(row=1, column=0)
Inc.configure(command= lambda arg=cntr:increment(arg))
Dec = Button(frame1,text='Dec')
Dec.grid(row=1, column=1)
Dec.configure(command= lambda arg=cntr:decrement(arg))

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok - playing with it a little more - here is one answer - but there has to be something more elegant using the original code I posted - I just don't understand why the original code does not work.  thank you in advance for looking at it

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import PhotoImage

def increment (event):
    global cntr
    print('in inc', cntr)
    cntr.set("{0:0>4}".format(cntr.get() + 1))

def decrement (event):
    global cntr
    print('in dec', cntr)
    cntr.set("{0:0>4}".format(cntr.get() - 1))

def EntryCB(arg):
    global cntr, counter1, counter2, counter3
    if arg == 1:
        cntr=counter1
    elif arg == 2:
        cntr=counter2
    elif arg == 3:
        cntr=counter3
    print('in EntryCB', cntr, arg)

root = Tk()
root.configure(bg='white')
frame1 = LabelFrame(root, text="Component 1",) 
frame1.grid()

#UpArrow = PhotoImage(file="images//UpArrow.png")
#DownArrow = PhotoImage(file="images/DownArrow.png")

counter1 = IntVar()
counter1.set("{0:0>4}".format(0))
counter2 = IntVar()
counter2.set("{0:0>4}".format(0))
counter3 = IntVar()
counter3.set("{0:0>4}".format(0))
cntr=1

print('in main', cntr)

Entry1 = Button(frame1, textvariable=counter1)
Entry1.grid(row=0, column=0)
Entry1.config(command= lambda arg=1:EntryCB(arg))
Entry1.configure(borderwidth=3, relief='sunken', bg='green')
Entry2 = Button(frame1, textvariable=counter2)
Entry2.grid(row=0, column=1)
Entry2.config(command= lambda arg=2:EntryCB(arg))
Entry2.configure(borderwidth=3, relief='sunken', bg='pink')
Entry3 = Button(frame1, textvariable=counter3)
Entry3.grid(row=0, column=2)
Entry3.config(command= lambda arg=3:EntryCB(arg))
Entry3.configure(borderwidth=3, relief='sunken', bg='orange')

Inc = Button(frame1,text='Inc')
Inc.bind("<Button-1>",increment)
Inc.grid(row=1, column=0)
#Inc.configure(command= lambda arg=cntr:increment(arg))
Dec = Button(frame1,text='Dec')
Dec.bind("<Button-1>",decrement)
Dec.grid(row=1, column=1)
#Dec.configure(command= lambda arg=cntr:decrement(arg))

root.mainloop()
```